# how do i download rstudio packages onto a linux debian 10 system?

Tags: r, linux, debian, rstudio

I use R Studio for university, but my laptop has a Chrome OS, so in order to actually *use* R Studio I needed to go through the built in Linux virtual machine. It took several hours of tinkering around and I got both it and tidyverse but for the life of me I can't figure out how I did it. The Linux uses Debian 10. For reference, i want to install the lsr and csr packages. Could anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`! The following may help you: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/

Comment: If you have already installed R using `install.packages()` from R console should do the job